# When should I include "note that"?

Tags: phrases, science

When writing scientific articles, I often feel that, for example,

> Note that the model can be solved exactly.

and

> The model can be solved exactly.

are equivalent. Other, similar phrases that are often used but seem to be not strictly necessary include "let us mention" and "let us point out". While including such phrases makes the language a bit more personal and engaging for the reader, the longer sentences may outweigh these benefits.

I would appreciate some guidance regarding when to use such phrases.

Answer (score 1):

To me, "note that" draws attention to the subject of the sentence. This implies that the reader should pay extra attention to what follows.

Well, at least that's how I use it in technical papers.

Comment: So you would say that "note that" does not indicate that the sentence is a note (additional information that is not essential) but in fact serves the opposite purpose, namely to highlight important information?

Comment: @painfulenglish I wouldn't say so... I think there are many reasons why "note that" would be used. Often times in internet forms or business applications a note is there because it doesn't apply to everyone (ex: accessibility), it's more aesthetically pleasing, or it's slightly off topic.